# Same RegExp returns different results - the first tim correct result, second time null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure some weird logic I am seeing in javascript, 
I have the next code:

```
var rgx = /(\S*)\s(\S*)/g;
rgx.exec("Yosi 1"); // returns ["Yosi 1","Yosi","1"]
rgx.exec("Yosi 1"); // returns null
rgx.exec("Yosi 1"); // returns ["Yosi 1","Yosi","1"]
```

Why on the second time I get null? I need to reset the regexp object somehow?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), the `lastIndex` property of the regular expression object is updated each time when using `g`.  After the first match, `lastIndex` will be at the end of the string, so when you compare it to the same string it starts to look for the match at the end so it won't find anything.

You can either not use `g` or use `.match` or some alternative depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

It is written in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) that

> If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object.

So, yes, you need to re-create the object, or, if you are just testing, use `.search()` method (as `test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property):

> If you are executing a match simply to find true or false, use the
>   RegExp.prototype.test() method or the String.prototype.search()
>   method.
>
> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec()
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>   When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by
>   the regular expression's lastIndex property (test() will also advance
>   the lastIndex property).

Or, you can "re-wind" the RegEx object to the starting position by setting the [`.lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) to `0`:

```js
var rgx = /(\S*)\s(\S*)/g;
alert(rgx.exec("Yosi 1")); // returns ["Yosi 1","Yosi","1"]
alert(rgx.exec("Yosi 1")); // returns null, and resets the object
alert(rgx.exec("Yosi 1")); // returns ["Yosi 1","Yosi","1"]
rgx.lastIndex = 0;         // reset it manually
alert(rgx.exec("Yosi 1")); // returns ["Yosi 1","Yosi","1"] again
```

Comment: Does setting lastIndex to zero is a bad practice? since match dosen't return the matches grouped it returns only ['Yosi 1']?

Comment: I think it is not a bad practice when you need *results*. Developers added "Writable --> yes" property attribute not for nothing, IMHO.